# JDBC Connection error -The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption

Tags: jdbc

I'm using IBM WAS 8.5 JRE for JDBC connection to SQL Server 2014. The connection string is as below -
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://DBT2:3433;MYDB;integratedSecurity=true";
I'm using Windows authentication so used integratedSecurity=true.3433 is the port number.

But I'm getting the below error -
The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.".

I've set the VM aurgemnets also to point to the correct authentication DLL file.

Still getting this error.

Please help!

Comment: what jdbc driver you use to connect to the DB

Comment: Sqljdbc type 4 driver

Comment: in your sql server configuration make sure that protocol TCP/IP is enabled and change the port to 3433

Comment: TCP/IP port is enabled and port has also changed to 3433.But still getting the same error

Comment: try connecto your sql server using JTDS jdbc driver, download it https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm able to connect it now

Comment: what have you done, changing the driver to jtds?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your JDBC drivers version is below 4.2 ,this may cause this issue.

The MS SQL Server JDBC driver and the MS SQL Server database) will always determine if a secure connection is possible. The Version 2 and Version 3 JDBC drivers use SSLv3. The Version 4 driver is able to use TLS.

please switch to latest JDBC driver and try again and see if this issue goes away.